# Send a binary file to WebDav using HTTP.put in Meteor

Tags: node.js, http, meteor, file-upload

I am trying to process a base64 encoded attachment from an E-Mail I receive from http://mailin.io/doc and send it to a WebDav server. Currently I am trying to do the following:

```
HTTP.call( 'PUT', 'https://path.to.owncloud/remote.php/webdav/mail2webdav/' + currentAttachment, {
    data: Meteor.call('base64Decode',file),
    auth: "user:pass"
  }, function( error, response ) {
    if ( error ) {
      console.log( error );
    } else {
      console.log( response );
    }
  });
```

While I receive a 201 return from the server and the file apperas on the webdav share, I am not able to open it.

Because of this request I am unsure that what I am trying to accomplish is possible using HTTP.put: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2450

Is there a common way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using the package `streamBuffers = Npm.require("stream-buffers");`

Then I put the data into the stream before uploading it

```js
      var myReadableStreamBuffer = new streamBuffers.ReadableStreamBuffer({
          frequency: 10,   // in milliseconds.
          chunkSize: 2048  // in bytes.
      });
      
      // Parse the base64 encoded attachment to the stream end close the stream
      myReadableStreamBuffer.put(postData[item.fileName], 'base64');
      myReadableStreamBuffer.stop();
```